# How to get values from specified table rows in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor-blaze

In my Meteor app, I have the following table which shows some info. Users can edit company name, address and email and save the changes by clicking the button beside.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Company Address</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Last Login</th>
      <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each users}}
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="companyName" value="{{companyName}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="companyAddress" value="{{companyAddress}}"</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="companyEmail" value="{{profile.email}}"></td>
      <td>{{date}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" value="Save">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="Delete">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In event handler:

```
'click .save':function(e,inst){
  var userID = this._id;
  var companyName = inst.$('[name=companyName]').val();
  var companyAddress = inst.$('[name=companyAddress]').val();
  var companyEmail = inst.$('[name=companyEmail]').val();

  console.log(companyName);
  console.log(userID);
  console.log(companyAddress);
  console.log(companyEmail);
}
```

By doing so, It only can read the values of the first row of table. Then I add data-id in input field `<td><input type="text" name="companyName" value="{{companyName}}" data-id="{{_id}}"></td>` It is able to get company name from the table row. My question is how to get the rest of attributes.

Comment: When there are multiple entries then you also need to iterate over each using `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate id for all input fields, I generally used to this like this

```
//in html    
<input type="text" name="companyName{{_id}}" value="{{companyName}}">

//in helper
var companyName = inst.$(`[name=companyName${this._id}]`).val();
```